# How To Bind To Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,[objectArray]>

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding, binding

Normally for binding in XAML we need to provide FIELDNAME, but in this case we have value like

```
Dictionary["xyz"]["abc"]
```

So is there any way to add `Dictionary["xyz"]["abc"]` in XAML?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have `ItemsSource` set to your `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, SOME_TYPE>>`. In this scenario, you can bind to `Key` and `Value`, where `Value` will be `Dictionary<string, SOME_TYPE>`.

What you can do then, is bind the `DataContext` of an element inside a DataTemplate (assuming that's what you're using) to that `Value`, and set the property binding to either the `Key` or `Value` of the child dictionary.